# Dynamic control not showing up on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, web-controls

This is relatively straight forward, but I'm obviously missing a step and cannot find support on resolving my issue.

I'm simply trying to append a dynamically created control to my page, but that is not happening. Here's a stripped down version of what I'm doing:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Click += new EventHandler(btnTakeAction_Click);
button.Text = "Take Action";
button.ID = "btnTakeAction";
fullPayOnlyCoupon = string.Format(
    "<div>Some random text. I want my control to show up here: {0}</div>", button);
```

Assume that `btnTakeAction_Click` is valid. Also, I know this won't show the button properly, but instead just render it something like `WebControl.Button`. But that is the idea of what I'm looking for: the button to show up in a specific spot in the dynamically created markup within a string. From what I understand, you must add this button control to another pre-existing control that is already on the page. So I've tried this:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Click += new EventHandler(btnTakeAction_Click);
button.Text = "Take Action";
button.ID = "btnTakeAction";
ControlOnAspxPage.Controls.Add(button);
```

But the `ControlOnAspxPage` does not render my dynamically created button.

Comment: (1) What's the type of `ControlOnAspxPage`? (2) Where (`Page_Load` maybe) are you running that code?

Comment: Did you try 'ControlOnAspxPage' to be a panel. And also make sure you are not auto redirect/refreshing the page which will cause the control to disapper quickly, since it is a dynamic control. The rest of your code works fine 'on my system'!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a [Placeholder control:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<asp:PlaceHolder
  EnableTheming="True|False"
  EnableViewState="True|False"
  ID="string"
  OnDataBinding="DataBinding event handler"
  OnDisposed="Disposed event handler"
  OnInit="Init event handler"
  OnLoad="Load event handler"
  OnPreRender="PreRender event handler"
  OnUnload="Unload event handler"
  runat="server"
  SkinID="string"
  Visible="True|False"
/>
```

With:

```
myButton = new HtmlButton();
myButton.InnerText = "Button 2";
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myButton);
```

Comment: Hi,you are not need to add dynamic controls in a placeholder, you are able to add dynamic control to every existing control you want ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your dynamic control each time in your `Page_Load` event.
Here is an explanation:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8114/Dynamically-Created-Controls-in-ASP-NET